# React-Native Hot/Live reload not working with git repo init

Tags: git, reactjs, react-native, hot-reload

I've started a new project using React-Native and it worked like a charm until I've started a new git repo. The problem is that when the project contains the folder ".git" it doesn't reload on any file change. I've tried to remove this folder (or moving all files onto a new project) and it works. Any idea?

(Using RN@0.52.0, expo@25.0.0, React@16.2.0)

Comment: What does " it doesn't reload on any file change" means? You can show the developer popup, select Hot reload but it's not working?

Comment: Yes, that's it. When for example I change the backgroundColor from a View and I save the file, it doesn't reload automatically, I need to close the "server" and execute it again...